# Module cifs not found on NanoPi M3 Ubuntu Core 15.10 although cifs-utils installs correctly

Tags: samba, cifs, 15.10

I'm trying to connect a smb-share of a FritzBox to my NanoPi M3 currently operating Ubuntu Core 15.10 (downloaded as sd image by manufacturer).

The network share is publicly accessable and up and running. I checked these via several Windows PC's and smbclient on my NanoPi (which is running without any problems).

But when I try to mount the share via `mount -t cifs -o username=guest -o password= -o uid=1000 //192.168.2.254/fritz.nas/[folder] /media/[folder]` I receive an error:
`mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

Folders are properly created and `mount.cifs -V` returns: `mount.cifs version: 6.4`.

I did no kernel update and already tried to reboot (as suggested elsewhere).

`ls -l /lib/modules/3.4.39-s5p4418/kernel/fs` returns `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 20  2016 ntfs` but no cifs.

Additionally I tried to install the whole samba-package with recommenended packages (tried to mount again of course), then purged all of them and reinstalled `cifs-utils`.

`lsmod` also has no recognized cifs module and `modprobe cifs` returns `modprobe: FATAL: Module cifs not found.` of course.

I hope someone of you already had this kind of problem and knows how to fix it. If you need more information, just leave a comment :) 
Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally made it** and will try to summarize my various 'repair' strategies now by what I think were the key operations:

Had to **recompile the kernel with cifs module activated** as described in http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_M3#Compile_Kernel_Modules **on another host** (installed Ubuntu Desktop in the same version on a VM) and then **copied** the generated **missing files to the NanoPi**.

After a reboot `modprobe` was able to find the cifs module and my mount procedure was successful.

Feel free to comment if you need some further explanations.