# Ubuntu Core adding a cifs share

Tags: networking, mount, ubuntu-core, cifs

I'm very new to Ubuntu Core and would like to mount a network share to my pi3.  Before I would just edit etc/fstab using cifs but when I try to use cifs it gives me an error `mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system`

When I try something like: `mount -t cifs -o username=guest -o password= -o uid=1000 //192.168.1.x/[folder] /media/[folder]`
I get:  `mount: /media/[folder]: cannot mount //192.168.1.x/[folder]/ read-only`.

I can't install cifs-utils either using sudo apt-get install or sudo install or snap install.  From what I've read cifs-utils is part of ubuntu-core but I can't figure out how to use it apparently.

I know this is a paired down os for IOT but I'm lost as to how to add a simple network share so that I can have network file storage.  And I may have just missed some simple thing but I can't find anything in my search for answers. I'm very rusty on my linux terminal commands but I'm pretty sure this is the right way to do it.

If anyone can help - my ultimate aim is to mount //192.168.1.x/foldername to ~/foldername
I'd like this to be a persistent mount. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Ubuntu Core 30 is not yet official so packages might be missing. If that's the version you are using, maybe it is better to install Ubuntu Core 18 instead.

Comment: This IS core 18,  Sorry if I was unclear on that.  The particular iso I have is using plexmediaserver-core18-pi.img.xz

Comment: What kind of network share? Make and model and how it is connected, NAS or what?

Comment: There is another similar post (3 years old) here: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/861288/module-cifs-not-found-on-nanopi-m3-ubuntu-core-15-10-although-cifs-utils-install?rq=1`

Comment: I saw that comment and used what I could figure out from it as best as I could before posting here but he doesn't really explain what his fix was so I was still lost.  My "other host" is fine and I have network shares from that host mounted on other linux boxes in my network (using cifs).  I just can't figure out how to get a network share working on this new ubuntu-core running on a Raspberry Pi 3.